# Smart filter in Bootstrap Vue

Tags: vuejs2, datatables, bootstrap-vue

I was wondering if there is any way to implement the Intelligent DataTables filter in the Bootstrap-Vue table, I have searched everywhere, but I have not found any functional solution to implement in my project.
[DataTable.net smart filter image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4Nij.png)

Comment: What do you mean with "smart filter"?

Comment: @Hiws In DataTable.net we can search in several fields at once giving space, for example in the image I am using the [example of the datatables search](https://datatables.net/examples/index)  exposed on their main website

Comment: The `filter`property on `b-table` accepts a regular expression, which you could use to get what you want. [here's](https://codepen.io/Hiws/pen/NWqXmRm) an example of how it could be done, but this only matches full words. I'm not good with regular expressions so i'm not sure how to make it do partial words too.

Comment: @Hiws I found it interesting !! I tried to use the example regex and got some errors, for example, it only showed the corresponding line if the word was all written if I write only the beginning and give space it breaks

Comment: That's what I said I my previous comment. It only matches full words and not partials. You'll have to find the proper regex to get it working. The above was more a proof of concept :)

Answer (score 0):

We needed that component so we created it. Hope it helps:
[image]

**SearchTable.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="search-table h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center"
       v-bind:class="{row: data.length === 0}" v-if="isMounted">


    <div v-if="data.length > 0">

      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">

        <!-- main search -->
        <b-input-group size="xs">
          <b-form-input v-model="searchInput"></b-form-input>
          <b-input-group-append is-text>
            <b-icon icon="search"></b-icon>
          </b-input-group-append>
        </b-input-group>

      </div>

      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mt-2 mb-0">
        <b-button-group>
          <!-- dropdown -->
          <b-dropdown id="col-dropdown" class="col-dropdown" no-flip text="Visibilité">
            <b-dropdown-item :key="field.key" class="p-0" style="padding: 0" v-for="field in fields"
                             v-if="field.key !== 'action'">
              <div @click.stop="onDropdownClick(field.key)"
                   class="checkbox-wrapper">
                <b-form-checkbox
                        :checked="isColumnDisplayed(field.key)"
                        disabled
                >
                  {{ field.label || field.key }}
                </b-form-checkbox>
              </div>
            </b-dropdown-item>
          </b-dropdown>
          <b-button :variant="noneOfSearchMethodIsUsed ? '' : 'danger'" @click="cancelFilters">Enlever filtre</b-button>

          <!-- dropdown action groupées -->
          <slot name="groupped-actions"></slot>

        </b-button-group>
        <div align="right" style="display: inline-flex">
          <span style="margin: 4px;">Afficher</span>
          <b-form-select
                  v-model="perPage"
                  :options="perPageOptions"
                  size="sm"
          ></b-form-select>
          <span style="margin: 4px;">éléments</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mt-0 mb-2">
        <span style="margin-top: 5px;">{{ buildInformationLine }}</span>
        <!-- pagination -->
        <b-pagination
                :per-page="perPage"
                :total-rows="formattedData.length"
                align="right"
                class="my-0 mt-1"
                size="sm"
                v-model="currentPage"
        ></b-pagination>
      </div>
      <!-- TABLE -->
      <b-table
              :current-page="currentPage"
              :fields="fieldsToShow"
              :items="formattedData"
              :per-page="perPage"
              foot-clone
              no-footer-sorting
              primary-key="id"
              :sticky-header="true"
              responsive
              striped
      >
        <!-- action col template -->
        <template
                v-if="!!$scopedSlots.action"
                v-slot:cell(action)="row">
          <slot name="action" v-bind="row.item"></slot>
        </template>

        <!-- html escape template -->
        <template v-slot:cell()="data">
          <span v-html="data.value"></span>
        </template>

        <!-- footer -->
        <template v-slot:foot()="data">
          <input :value="getFieldFromKey(data.column).searchVal"
                 @input="setFieldSearchValue(data.column, $event.target.value)"
                 v-if="getFieldFromKey(data.column).key !== 'action'"
                 class="w-100"
                 placeholder="Recherche">
        </template>

      </b-table>

      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mt-0">
        <span style="margin-top: 5px;">{{ buildInformationLine }}</span>
        <!-- pagination -->
        <b-pagination
                :per-page="perPage"
                :total-rows="formattedData.length"
                align="right"
                class="my-0 mt-1"
                size="sm"
                v-model="currentPage"
        ></b-pagination>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div v-else>
      <p>Aucun résultat</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script lang="ts">
  import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
  import BvTableField from '../../interfaces/BvTableField'

  enum SearchFusionMethod {
    Union = 'union',
    Intersection = 'intersection',
  }

  interface FieldsInteractiveInterface extends BvTableField {
    searchVal: string
    stickyColumn: boolean
  }

  @Component
  export default class SearchTable extends Vue {
    // The array containing the data objects
    @Prop(Array) readonly data!: any[]
    // The array containing the info of each column. key must be equal to key in object data
    @Prop(Array) readonly fields!: BvTableField[]
    @Prop({default: SearchFusionMethod.Intersection}) readonly searchFusionMethod!: SearchFusionMethod
    @Prop({default: 'highlight'}) readonly highlighterClass!: string
    mainHighlighterClass: string = this.highlighterClass
    @Prop({default: 'field-highlight'}) readonly fieldHighlighterClass!: string
    currentPage = 1
    perPage = 10
    perPageOptions = [10, 25, 50, 100]
    searchInput = ''
    isMounted = false
    // Contains the value of each column search field
    fieldsInteractive: FieldsInteractiveInterface[] = []

    // ---
    mainHilightColor: string = 'yellow'
    fieldHilightColor: string = 'orange'

    get fieldsToShow(): BvTableField[] {
      return this.fieldsInteractive.filter(field => {
        return field.display
      })
    }

    get noneColumnSearchFieldIsUsed(): boolean {
      return this.numberOfSearchFieldsUsed === 0
    }

    get numberOfSearchFieldsUsed(): number {
      return this.fieldsInteractive.reduce((count: number, field) => {
        return count + (field.searchVal !== '' ? 1 : 0)
      }, 0)
    }

    // (01), (10)
    get exactlyOneSearchMethodIsUsed(): boolean {
      return (this.searchInput !== '' && this.noneColumnSearchFieldIsUsed) || (this.searchInput === '' && !this.noneColumnSearchFieldIsUsed)
    }

    // (00)
    get noneOfSearchMethodIsUsed(): boolean {
      return (this.searchInput === '' && this.noneColumnSearchFieldIsUsed)
    }

    // (11)
    get bothSearchMethodsAreUsed(): boolean {
      return (this.searchInput !== '' && !this.noneColumnSearchFieldIsUsed)
    }

    get onlyMainSearchIsUsed(): boolean {
      return (this.searchInput !== '' && this.noneColumnSearchFieldIsUsed)
    }

    get onlyFieldSearchIsUsed(): boolean {
      return (this.searchInput === '' && !this.noneColumnSearchFieldIsUsed)
    }

    get buildInformationLine(): string {
      const txt: String[] = []
      txt.push("Affichage de l'élément")
      txt.push(this.formattedData.length === 0 ? '0' : (((this.currentPage-1) *  this.perPage)+1).toString())
      txt.push('à')
      txt.push((this.currentPage * this.perPage < this.formattedData.length ? this.currentPage * this.perPage : this.formattedData.length).toString())
      txt.push('sur')
      txt.push((this.formattedData.length).toString())
      txt.push('éléments')
      if (this.formattedData.length < this.data.length) {
        txt.push('(filtré de')
        txt.push((this.data.length).toString())
        txt.push('éléments au total)')
      }
      return txt.join(' ')
    }

    // Data with
    get formattedData() {
      const mapped = this.data
              .map((item: any) => {
                const itemWithHighlight: any = {}
                this.fields.forEach(field => {
                  itemWithHighlight[field.key] = this.replaceBySearch(field.key, item[field.key])
                })
                return itemWithHighlight
              })

      return mapped
              .filter((item: any) => {
                //                                                                                                      (searchInput,columnSearchField)
                // If there is no filter at all, return the row                                                         (00)
                if (this.noneOfSearchMethodIsUsed) return true

                let countFromMainHighlight = 0
                let countFromFieldHighlight = 0

                // loop through each field
                for (const [key, col] of Object.entries(item)) {
                  if (!this.fieldsInteractive[this.fieldsInteractive.findIndex(x => x.key === key)].display) continue // Only search in displayed column
                  if (typeof col !== 'string') continue // only check in string values

                  if (this.onlyMainSearchIsUsed) {
                    // if only one of the search method has been used, return anything having a 'highlight' class       (01), (10)
                    if (col.includes('fromMainSearch') || col.includes(this.fieldHighlighterClass)) {
                      return true
                    }
                  } else {

                    // if both of the search method have been used, filter according to the searchFusionMethod          (11)
                    if (this.searchFusionMethod === SearchFusionMethod.Intersection) {

                      // TODO: search only in class attribute of markup (faster)
                      if (col.includes('fromMainSearch')) {
                        countFromMainHighlight++
                      }
                      if (col.includes('fromFieldSearch')) {
                        countFromFieldHighlight++
                      }
                    } else if (this.searchFusionMethod === SearchFusionMethod.Union) {
                      if (col.includes(`<span class="${this.highlighterClass}`)) {
                        // TODO
                        return true
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }

                // determine whether we keep the row
                if (this.bothSearchMethodsAreUsed) {
                  return countFromMainHighlight > 0 && countFromFieldHighlight === this.numberOfSearchFieldsUsed
                } else {
                  if (this.onlyMainSearchIsUsed) {
                    return countFromFieldHighlight > 0
                  } else if (this.onlyFieldSearchIsUsed) {

                    return countFromFieldHighlight === this.numberOfSearchFieldsUsed
                  }
                }
              })
    }

    isColumnDisplayed(key: string) {
      const field = this.getFieldFromKey(key)
      return field.display
    }

    setFieldSearchValue(key: string, searchVal: string) {
      const index = this.fieldsInteractive.findIndex(field => field.key === key)
      if (index === -1) throw new DOMException('Key not found')
      Vue.set(this.fieldsInteractive, index, {
        ...this.fieldsInteractive[index],
        searchVal: searchVal
      })
      // this.fieldsInteractive[index].searchVal = searchVal
    }

    mounted() {
      // programatically add action column if slot given
      if (!!this.$scopedSlots.action) {
        const fieldAction = {key: 'action'}
        this.fields.push(fieldAction)
      }

      // init column search values
      this.fields.forEach(field => {
        if (field.key === 'action') {
          this.fieldsInteractive.unshift({
            ...field,
            searchVal: '',
            sortable: false,
            display: field.display ?? true,
            stickyColumn: true
          })
        } else {
          this.fieldsInteractive.push({
            ...field,
            searchVal: '',
            sortable: field.sortable ?? true,
            display: field.display ?? true,
            stickyColumn: false
          })
        }
      })
      this.isMounted = true
    }

    onDropdownClick(key: string) {
      for (const index in this.fieldsInteractive) {
        if (this.fieldsInteractive[index].key === key) {
          this.fieldsInteractive[index].display = !this.fieldsInteractive[index].display // toggle
          return
        }
      }
    }

    private cancelFilters(): void {
      this.fieldsInteractive = this.fieldsInteractive.map((field) => {
        field.searchVal = ''
        return field
      })
      this.searchInput = ''
    }

    private getFieldFromKey(key: string): FieldsInteractiveInterface {
      const f = this.fieldsInteractive.find(field => field.key === key)
      if (f === undefined) {
        throw new DOMException('Key not found')
      }
      return f
    }

    private replaceBySearch(key: string, str: string | any) {
      if ((this.searchInput === '' && this.noneColumnSearchFieldIsUsed)
              || str === undefined || str === null) return str

      str = String(str)

      // main search bar
      if (this.exactlyOneSearchMethodIsUsed || this.bothSearchMethodsAreUsed) {
        const regexMain: RegExp | undefined = this.searchInput !== '' ? new RegExp(`${this.searchInput}`, 'i') : undefined
        const regexField: RegExp | undefined = this.getFieldFromKey(key).searchVal !== '' ? new RegExp(`${this.getFieldFromKey(key).searchVal}`, 'i') : undefined
        const matchMain: string[] | null = regexMain ? (str).match(regexMain) : null
        const matchField: string[] | null = regexField ? (str).match(regexField) : null

        if (matchMain || matchField) {
          str = this.surroundWithHilightClass(str, matchMain, matchField)
        }
      }

      return str
    }

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-can-i-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string
    // replace only if not already contains a highlight class

    /**
     * @param str string to be surrounded
     * @param findMain what is matching with main search
     * @param findField what is matching with field search
     */
    private surroundWithHilightClass(str: string, findMain: string[] | null, findField: string[] | null) {
      const main: string | null = findMain && findMain.length > 0 ? findMain[0] : null
      const field: string | null = findField && findField.length > 0 ? findField[0] : null

      str = String(str)

      // if a search is in another search, put two classes
      if (field && main?.includes(field)) {
        str = str.replace(new RegExp(main, 'g'), `<span class="${this.mainHighlighterClass} fromFieldSearch fromMainSearch">${main}</span>`)
      } else if (main && field?.includes(main)) {
        str = str.replace(new RegExp(field, 'g'), `<span class="${this.mainHighlighterClass} fromMainSearch fromFieldSearch">${field}</span>`)
      } else {
        // here we are sur the highlightning will be separated (this prevents having span in span)
        if (main) {
          str = str.replace(new RegExp(main, 'g'), `<span class="${this.mainHighlighterClass} fromMainSearch">${main}</span>`)
        }
        if (field) {
          str = str.replace(new RegExp(field, 'g'), `<span class="${this.fieldHighlighterClass} fromFieldSearch">${field}</span>`)
        }
      }
      return str
    }

  }
</script>


<style lang="scss">
  .search-table {
    div {
      p {
        color: gray;
        text-align: center;
      }
    }

    span.fromFieldSearch {
      background-color: orange; // not defined : var(--main-highlighter-class);
    }

    /* Why this overrides fromFielSearch even if fromFieldSearch appear after in class order ? */
    span.fromMainSearch {
      background-color: yellow; // not defined : var(--field-highlighter-class);
    }

    span.field-highlight {
      background-color: orange;
    }

    .col-dropdown {
      .dropdown-item {
        padding: 0 !important;
      }
    }

    .checkbox-wrapper {
      padding: 4px 24px;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .custom-control-input[disabled] ~ .custom-control-label, .custom-control-input:disabled ~ .custom-control-label {
      color: #000 !important;
    }

    .b-table-sticky-header > .table.b-table > thead > tr > th {
      top: -2px !important;
    }

    .b-table-sticky-header {
      max-height: calc(125vh - 400px) !important;
    }

    .b-table-sticky-header > .table.b-table > tfoot > tr > th {
      position: sticky;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: white;
      z-index: 0;
    }

    th.b-table-sticky-column {
      z-index: 4 !important;
    }
  }
</style>
```

The code is a bit messy but it works.
Note: we use vue class component with vuw property decorators